# How to write an RSocket client in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, websocket, reactive-streams, rsocket

I try to implement an RSocket server in Java and a client in JavaScript, but I can't call any of the methods in my backend.

**Java server**

```
public final class RawServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RSocketFactory.receive()
                .acceptor((setup, sendingSocket) -> Mono.just(new DefaultSimpleService()))
                .transport(WebsocketServerTransport.create("localhost", 8801))
                .start()
                .block()
                .onClose()
                .block();
    }

    private static final class DefaultSimpleService extends AbstractRSocket {
        private ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        @Override
        public Flux<Payload> requestStream(Payload payload) {
            return Mono.just(payload.getDataUtf8())
                    .map(json -> {
                        try {
                            return jsonMapper.readValue(json, Message.class);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        }
                    })
                    .doOnNext(msg -> System.out.println("got message " + msg.message))
                    .flatMapMany(msg -> Flux.range(0, 5)
                            .map(count -> msg.message + " #" + count))
                    .map(message -> DefaultPayload.create(message));
        }
    }
}

public class Message {

    public final String message;

    @JsonCreator
    public Message(@JsonProperty("message") String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript client**

```
    import { RSocketClient, JsonSerializers } from "rsocket-core";
    import RSocketWebSocketClient from "rsocket-websocket-client";

    const transport = new RSocketWebSocketClient({
        url: "ws://localhost:8801"
      });

      const client = new RSocketClient({
        // send/receive JSON objects instead of strings/buffers
        serializers: JsonSerializers,
        setup: {
          // ms btw sending keepalive to server
          keepAlive: 60000,
          // ms timeout if no keepalive response
          lifetime: 180000,
          // format of `data`
          dataMimeType: "application/json",
          // format of `metadata`
          metadataMimeType: "application/json"
        },
        transport
      });
      client.connect().subscribe({
        onComplete: socket => {
          socket.requestStream({
            data: { message: "hello from javascript!" },
            metadata: null
          });
        },
        onError: error => {
          console.log("got error");
          console.error(error);
        },
        onSubscribe: cancel => {
          /* call cancel() to abort */
          console.log("subscribe!");
          console.log(cancel);
          // cancel.cancel();
        }
      });
```

It seems like the WebSocket connection is established, but no message is pushed to the server. How can I do this?

I also implemented the client side in Java and it work's fine. The JavaScript example I found is https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/blob/master/docs/01-client-configuration.md, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more examples with RSocket you can visit my personal blog http://kojotdev.com/2019/09/rsocket-examples-java-javascript-spring-webflux/

Ok, I figured it out. First, we need to fix our server to return the correct JSON object.

```
@Override
public Flux<Payload> requestStream(Payload payload) {
    log.info("got requestStream in Server");
    log.info(payload.getDataUtf8());
    return Mono.just(payload.getDataUtf8())
            .map(payloadString -> MessageMapper.jsonToMessage(payloadString))
            .flatMapMany(msg -> Flux.range(0, 5)
                    .map(count -> msg.message + " | requestStream from Server #" + count)
                    .map(responseText -> new Message(responseText))
                    .map(responseMessage -> MessageMapper.messageToJson(responseMessage)))
            .map(message -> DefaultPayload.create(message));
}
```

Then, in our JavaScript client, we need to change the `socket.requestStream` method to this:

```
socket
  .requestStream({
    data: { message: "request - stream from javascript!" },
    metadata: ""
  })
  .subscribe({
    onComplete: () => console.log("requestStream done"),
    onError: error => {
      console.log("got error with requestStream");
      console.error(error);
    },
    onNext: value => {
      // console.log("got next value in requestStream..");
      console.log(value.data);
    },
    // Nothing happens until `request(n)` is called
    onSubscribe: sub => {
      console.log("subscribe request Stream!");
      sub.request(7);
    }
  });
```

Everything else stays as in the previous example.
Helpful links:

- Client API https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/blob/master/docs/02-client-api.md
- Flowable API https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/blob/master/docs/03-flowable-api.md
- RSocket examples (Java, JavaScript, Spring WebFlux) http://kojotdev.com/2019/09/rsocket-examples-java-javascript-spring-webflux/

Comment: Why if i execut this code twice it gives me that the client is already connected?

Comment: Because probably you call the `client.connect()` twice. In the `onComplete` event of `client.connect()` store the `socket` to the global variable. Then just call the methods like `socket.requestResponse()` etc.